# DotNetCore routing attribute extend url

Tags: c#, .net

I have .Net Core 5 app.In my Home controller I try to extend action route on the same named actions.
But when I call Currencies with

/home/currencies/historic/1

does not work 404.Where I am wrong.The 2nd action also have route "{based}"

> /home/currencies/EUR

,why I can access him and why not the last action?

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Currencies([FromServices] ApiClient client)
    {

[HttpGet("{based}")]
    public async Task<string> Currencies(
        [FromServices] ApiClient client,
        [FromRoute] string based)
    {

[HttpGet("historic/{days}")]
    public async Task<string> Currencies(
        [FromServices] ApiClient client,
        int days)
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet("/currencies/historic/{days}")]
    public async Task<string> Currencies(
        [FromServices] ApiClient client,
        [FromRoute] int days)
    {
```

Also, put attribute [ApiController] to your controller

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that you should try with `[FromRoute]` attribute before `int days`?